Как получить часы в питонe?
Мне надо получить время в питоне в часах, но максимально коротким способом, то есть стандартный способ слишком длинный:
cu = datetime.datetime.now().time()
cu1 = cu.hour 

Можете подсказать короткий способ, который будет занимать меньше места с файле?

можно используя модуль datetime => from datetime import datetime as dt (dt - alias) => cu1 = dt.now().hour

Ну да, промежуточная переменная не нужна и промежуточный вызов time() тоже не нужен. А если у вас этот код много раз повторяется, то напишите метод, который и вызывайте, когда вам нужно будет. Для этого методы/функции и нужны, чтобы не повторять длинный код каждый раз.

Спасибо большое
